# Print distance from current location to another location javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I got the below code to calculate the distance from current location to another location, Can anyone please help me how to merge this code in HTML file and print the distance on that HTML page?

I have less idea about JavaScript. Please help.

```
var Geolocation = {
  rad: function(x) { return x * Math.PI / 180 },

  // Distance in kilometers between two points using the Haversine algo.
  haversine: function(p1, p2) {
    var R = 6371
    var dLat  = this.rad(p2.latitude - p1.latitude)
    var dLong = this.rad(p2.longitude - p1.longitude)

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(this.rad(p1.latitude)) * Math.cos(this.rad(p2.latitude)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2)
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))
    var d = R * c

    return Math.round(d)
  },

  // Distance between me and the passed position.
  distance_from: function(position) {
    Geolocation.display_location()
    var distance = Geolocation.haversine(position.coords, current_location)

    // Sugar: If distance is less than 1km, don't bump into me.
    if ( distance && distance > 0 ) $("#distance").text(distance + " km")
    else $("#user_distance").html("<strong>You're close!</strong> Watch my toes!")
  },

  // Hide spinner and show location.
  display_location: function() {
    $("#user_distance").show()
    $("#geolocating").hide()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to come from this blog: http://breakthebit.org/post/10512237123/using-html5-geolocation-api-to-get-the-distance-of

There is a demo at: http://miha.rebernik.info/

It ends up being simply:

1. [Include jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) JavaScript library in your page.
2. Add the appropriate HTML containers (ids `user_distance`, `distance` and possibly `geolocating`).
3. Use the [geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) to call the methods defined by your piece of code

**Code example:**

1. jQuery include:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

2. HTML containers:

```html
<p id="geolocating">Please share your location…</p>

<p id="user_distance">
    Distance from position (latitude: YY, longitude: XX) to you:
    <span id="distance"></span>
</p>
```

3. Geolocation call:

```js
var current_location = {
    latitude: 48.86,
    longitude: 2.35
};

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Geolocation.distance_from, Geolocation.display_location);
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(Geolocation.distance_from);
} else {
    Geolocation.display_location();
}
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/zk8Ph9mNIaPsyFpWd8u4?p=preview